minimal cuts and pastes to make a t-shirt?
(I have not found an exercise about this in do Carmo or Struik, and I think it could go a long way towards building intuition about curvature and develop skills in computing special 2D areas, as well as basic topological ideas of surgery and simplicial complexes)
For fun and learning, I would like to cut a piece of rigid cloth (i.e., similar to a piece of paper, no stretch) to make a t-shirt.  I wonder what number of cuts I need to make and what number and size of additional pieces of cloth I need to paste to it.  Assume we can sew pieces of fabric along parallel, matched edges.
Because a t-shirt has at least one point of negative Gauss curvature somewhere around the under-arm, I expect I will have to cut the paper/cloth to bend it / curve it into a t-shirt shape and possibly glue some other pieces to make it close up.
Here is a rough outline of an algorithm:

center the 2w(idth) x 2h(eight) rectangular fabric at the origin, edges parallel to the x,y axes

cut out a rectangle or disk in the center for the head.

cut horizontally inward twice for length a<w, parallel to the x axis, at heights y=s and y=-s, starting from w and -w.  These cuts will be the sleeves.

at x=w\pm a, cut vertically towards the x axis at the edge of the cut from (2) to make it possible to close up the sleeves.  Make the sleeves into a prism (cylinder over a triangle) by folding along two lines so that the sleeves close up.

now cut horizontally so as to make a it possible to close up the torso by making additional folds.  This leaves a gap between the closed up torso and the closed up sleeves.

paste a portion of the fabric cut out for the head/neck to connect the sleeves to the torso.  This could be a simple rectangle sewn along the original cuts.  But it's possible to reduce the area of the attached piece by folding two triangles outward from the torso.


Ideally one could:

minimize the number of fabric cuts (I think 9) and fabric pastes (I think 2)

within that, minimize the area of pasted fabric or the length of sewing intervals

calculate the areas of the attached fabric, either in the case where the t-shirt is folded along straight lines, or where the arms and torso are made into partially cylindrical shapes.


PS: another t-shirt question
Intrinsic Curvature of a T-Shirt
points out that there is some amount of "theoretical" modeling going on here in that without some stretching it would be hard to wear the resulting object.
PPS: perhaps there are pair-of-pants exercises along these lines; I haven't found ones yet.

Topologically a T-shirt is just a sphere with 4 holes, which can be made from a sheet with no cutting. How are you defining a T-shirt?

yes topologically that's what I mean, but I was also intending it as a geometric object where one can try to calculate the minimal area that needs to be added in. I'm assuming one would take a rectangular sheet of paper and bend it or crease it along lines.

You mention that you might accept a T-shirt that is "hard to wear" - so what exactly do you require in order to consider it a valid T-shirt?
